# Write each element of a set as a sum of the combinations of the elements of another set

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any problem related to this? Or advice on how to approach a problem like this.

> Given a set $A$ that contains the series $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, prove whether it is possible to write the elements of another set $B$ as a sum of $k$ combinations of $a_n$.

For example, I have an arbitrary series $\{a_n\}$, how do I prove/disprove that the elements of $B$ can be written as:
$$b_n=\overbrace{a_1+a_2+a_3+...}^{k \text{ times}}$$

Specifically, in my case, set $B$ contains all natural numbers, how do I approach the problem? i.e. to show that:
$$\begin{align}
1=&\text{combination of $a_n$}\\
2=&\text{combination of $a_n$}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Something like [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem).  Or the various sumset problems in combinatorial number theory.